# Hiding 'Inc TAX/VAT' in Product Listing on Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Other than cheating and adding this CSS:

```
.products-list .price-including-tax { display:none; }
```

Does anyone know how I can remove the 'Inc TAX/VAT' in the products listings but not in the individual product pages?

I believe I can do it with price.phtml template file, although I'm not sure what original code should be in there to edit it as it doesn't exist on my setup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are Using Default theme then go to the following Location:

\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml

Here you can Hide the Text.

Comment: I'm not no, i'm using a custom theme. Be I had a look in my default theme folder and can't find that file to copy across.

Comment: Managed to find price.phtml in another theme and used that. Thanks.